# how to add condition for a column which has decode on it

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql in the below format:

```
SELECT aggregate_target_name,
       target_name,
       target_type,
       host_name,
       MAX(DECODE(mc.metric_column, 'CREATED', mc.value)) CREATED,
       MAX(DECODE(tp.property_name, 'DBVersion', tp.property_value)) VERSION,
       MAX(DECODE(tp.property_name, 'DGstatus', tp.property_value)) DGstatus
  FROM mgmt$metric_current mc
  JOIN mgmt$target t
    ON mc.target_name = t.target_name
  JOIN mgmt$target_members tm
    ON mc.target_name = tm.member_target_name
   AND tm.aggregate_target_name IN ('ORACLE_PROD_TARGETS')
  JOIN mgmt$target_properties tp
    ON mc.target_name = tp.target_name
 WHERE metric_name = 'ME$DB_LINKS'
 GROUP BY tm.aggregate_target_name,
          mc.target_name,
          mc.target_type,
          key_value,
          t.host_name)
```

How can i add conditions such that the columns `'CREATED is not null'` and `'DGstatus!=standby'`.
Current output for column CREATED (from sqldeveloper):

```
(null)
12-JAN-2019 04:18:03
26-SEP-2020 00:19:53
(null)
18-AUG-2011 18:36:16
03-FEB-2012 17:25:41
13-SEP-2019 16:03:11
09-DEC-2019 11:47:37
```

For DGstatus:

```
Primary
Primary
Primary
Physical Standby
Physical Standby
Physical Standby
Physical Standby
Physical Standby
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `having` clause:

```
HAVING MAX(DECODE(mc.metric_column, 'CREATED', mc.value)) IS NOT NULL AND
       MAX(DECODE(tp.property_name, 'DBVersion', tp.property_value)) <> 'standby'
```

I'm not a fan of using `DECODE()`, because standard SQL has a perfectly fine method to expression conditional logic, `CASE`.  But that is not actually relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can replace `DECODE` with `NVL2` function such as

   ```
   MAX(NVL2(mc.metric_column,'CREATED IS NOT NULL',mc.value)) AS Created2
   ```

   where the second argument stands for `NOT NULL` case
2. Need to add one more `DECODE` with four arguments, the fourth argument
   represents the `ELSE` case

   ```
   MAX(DECODE(tp.property_name, 'DGstatus', 
       DECODE(tp.property_value,'standby',tp.property_value,'DGstatus!=standby'),
              tp.property_value)) AS DGstatus2
   ```

You can replace those literals according to your reqirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE` rather than `DECODE`:

```sql
SELECT aggregate_target_name,
       target_name,
       target_type,
       host_name,
       MAX(
         CASE
         WHEN mc.metric_column = 'CREATED'
         THEN mc.value
         WHEN mc.metric_column IS NOT NULL
         THEN 'Not Null'
         ELSE 'Null'
         END
       ) AS CREATED,
       MAX(DECODE(tp.property_name, 'DBVersion', tp.property_value)) VERSION,
       MAX(
         CASE
         WHEN tp.property_name = 'DGstatus'
         THEN tp.property_value
         WHEN tp.property_name = 'DGstatus!=standby'
         THEN 'Not Standby'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
         END
       ) DGstatus
  FROM mgmt$metric_current mc
  JOIN mgmt$target t
    ON mc.target_name = t.target_name
  JOIN mgmt$target_members tm
    ON mc.target_name = tm.member_target_name
   AND tm.aggregate_target_name IN ('ORACLE_PROD_TARGETS')
  JOIN mgmt$target_properties tp
    ON mc.target_name = tp.target_name
 WHERE metric_name = 'ME$DB_LINKS'
 GROUP BY tm.aggregate_target_name,
          mc.target_name,
          mc.target_type,
          key_value,
          t.host_name)
```